# SQL Query Username not coming when I use WHERE IN condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display all the user post whom I am following and also my own posts.

But there is a problem with my query and the `username` result: When executed, I am getting the post correctly but the user details are wrong. It shows the same user details for all the posts. I suspect my `WHERE ... IN` clause is wrong.

```
SELECT u.username,
       u.NAME,
       u.profile_pic,
       up.*
FROM   USER u,
       user_post up
WHERE  up.user_id IN ( (SELECT follow_id
                        FROM   follow
                        WHERE  follow_id = $user_id), $user_id )
       AND description = ''
ORDER  BY postime DESC
```

How can I get the `user_post` for the relevant user.

Answer (score 0):

You miss to add the foreign key constraint in where statement

```
SELECT u.username,u.name,u.profile_pic, up.* FROM user u, user_post 
up where up.user_id = u.id and up.user_id in (SELECT follow_id FROM follow WHERE follow_id=$user_id) AND description='' order by postime desc
```

Comment: this query is giving error like this #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row I feel still the problem is in WHERE IN condition

Answer (score 0):

There's no join condition between user and user_post. If you used JOIN syntax this couldn't happen as the parser will complain about the missing ON.

(After your comment I added the IN back):

```
SELECT u.username,u.name,u.profile_pic, up.* 
FROM user u JOIN user_post up 
  ON up.user_id = u.id
WHERE 
   (up.user_id  = $user_id 
    OR
    up.user_id IN (
                     SELECT user_id 
                     FROM follow 
                     WHERE follow_id=$user_id
                   )
   )
AND description='' 
ORDER BY postime DESC
```

Comment: We need WHERE IN because I want to display the posts of the users I am following.

Comment: Nope, `SELECT follow_id FROM follow WHERE follow_id=$user_id` returns either no row or `$user_id`. You might need something like `SELECT user_id FROM follow WHERE follow_id=$user_id` instead :-)

Comment: I'm not convinced that SO should be promoting a JOIN style that disappeared with the last ice age.

Comment: @Strawberry: Tell that to Oracle users :-) I never write old style joins myself, but they're still part of Standard SQL and one should fix the query logic first and then start teaching lessons on how to join properly. But I'll edit my answer...

Comment: This query works without error but still the results are not coming correctly username and post is right but I am NOT getting all the users posts that I am following, I am getting my own post

Comment: I checked my logic again and this should return both, posts from this specific user and users he is following. You need to post more details, e.g the DDL of your tables.

Answer (score 0):

You not mention any user_post in sub Query .. (SELECT follow_id FROM follow WHERE follow_id=$user_id)

So, use inner join in user table.. SELECT follow_id FROM follow inner join user_post up on follow_id=up.user_id

Try this :

```
SELECT  u.username,
        u.name,
        u.profile_pic,
        up.* 
FROM    user u,user_post up 
where   up.user_id in 
(SELECT follow_id FROM follow inner join user_post up follow_id=up.user_id) 
AND    description=''
order by postime desc
```

Comment: Could you please remove this answer and merge it with your other answer? You can press the edit button below your first answer to merge/edit it.

Comment: I feel this might come close to solving problem but I am getting error  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'follow_id=up.user_id) AND description='' order by postime desc LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Add Alias :SELECT f.follow_id FROM follow f inner join user_post up f.follow_id=up.user_id